# Keep only a few specific lines inside some text files using RegEx for mass text replacement?

Tags: regex, windows, replace

Wanted to modify all my MAME\ini\ files (simple text *.ini files) keeping inside only the lines:

```
#  
# OSD PER-WINDOW VIDEO OPTIONS  
#  
aspect0          xx:xx
```

Starting from something like this:

```
...
#
# OSD PERFORMANCE OPTIONS
#
numprocessors             auto
bench                     0

#
# OSD VIDEO OPTIONS
#
video                     opengl
numscreens                1
window                    0
maximize                  0
waitvsync                 0
monitorprovider           auto

#
# OSD PER-WINDOW VIDEO OPTIONS
#
screen                    auto
aspect                    auto
resolution                auto
view                      auto
screen0                   auto
aspect0                   17:10
resolution0               auto
view0                     auto
screen1                   auto
aspect1                   auto
resolution1               auto
view1                     auto
screen2                   auto
aspect2                   auto
resolution2               auto
view2                     auto
screen3                   auto
aspect3                   auto
resolution3               auto
view3                     auto
...
```

where xx:xx can be 4:3, 17:10 or anything else (any specified screen ratio)... The spaces between aspect0 and xx may vary.
Everything else (= all other lines) should be removed and only those lines (if present) should remain. If those lines were not present, an empty file left will be fine (i.e. remove all non matching lines).

I'm using grepWin for mass text replacement (with RegEx support)...

I'm not sure how to specify those complex RegEx patterns

Answer (score 1):

At the moment this is the best solution I've found by myself:

```
^(?!.*(\#\r\n)?(\# OSD PER-WINDOW VIDEO))(?!aspect0).*$
```

It will replace all other lines with "\r\n" and leave just "# OSD PER-WINDOW..." titles and "aspect0" line as I wanted, like:

```
#  
# OSD PER-WINDOW VIDEO OPTIONS  
  
aspect0          xx:xx
```

Can't find something better ATM to remove useless "\r\n" in one go and keep third #. Hope will help others too, while waiting for a better reply.

Comment: Just adding "\r\n" in front of the search string: `\r\n^(?!.*(\#\r\n)?(\# OSD PER-WINDOW VIDEO))(?!aspect0).*$` seems to work to remove also \r\n!
The last missing thing is the third #, I can't exclude with my limited RegEx knowledge...

Comment: Even better `(\n)^(?!.*(\# OSD PER-WINDOW))(?!aspect0).*$`